# How do I print the number of a row in a two dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I am writing in C# and am trying to number the rows in a printed array. I have no clue how to do it with how I printed the two dimensional array.

It is intended to write like so:

> Row 0  # # # # # #
>
> Row 1  # # # # # #
>
> Row 2  # # # # # #

```
   int[,] array1 = new int[6, 6]
        {
            {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
            {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
            {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
            {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
            {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
            {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
        };

        int Length = array1.GetLength(0);
        int Height = array1.GetLength(1);
        Console.WriteLine("  Col 0  Col 1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4  Col 5");
        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0,6} ", array1[i, j]));
            }
            Console.Write("\n" + "\n");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `i` is the row number, right? Why not just write `i` to the console before printing out the rest of the row?

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to use names like `row` and `col` instead of `i` and `j`. Then it might be more obvious that you can just add `Console.Write($"Row {row} "); as the first line in the first `for` loop body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write the `Row 0`, `Row 1` etc inside the first loop but outside the second loop, and you should use `Console.Write()`, not `Console.WriteLine()`.

```
var array1 = new int[6, 6]
{
    {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
    {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
    {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
    {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
    {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
    {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
};

int Length = array1.GetLength(0);
int Height = array1.GetLength(1);
for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Row {0} : ", i);
    for (var j = 0; j < Height; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,6} ", array1[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Note the `Console.WriteLine()` at the end of each outer loop iteration which will take you to a new line before the next iteration.

### Output

> Row 0 : 10 20 10 20 21 99
>
> Row 1 : 2 27 5 45 20 13
>
> Row 2 : 17 20 20 33 33 20
>
> Row 3 : 21 35 15 54 20 37
>
> Row 4 : 31 101 25 55 26 66
>
> Row 5 : 45 20 44 12 55 98

Answer (score 1):

You simply can write to the console before printing the value of the array row.

```
   int[,] array1 = new int[6, 6]
        {
            {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
            {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
            {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
            {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
            {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
            {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
        };

        int Length = array1.GetLength(0);
        int Height = array1.GetLength(1);
        Console.WriteLine("  Col 0  Col 1  Col 2  Col 3  Col 4  Col 5");
        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Row {0} ", i); // Outside of the loop :)
            for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0,6} ", array1[i, j]));
            }
            Console.Write("\n" + "\n");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```